How to troubleshoot audio and controller issues with Retroarch and OBS on macOS 14.1
edit: It seems this question is off-topic, so perhaps it should be closed. I'm pursuing this in the Retroarch Discord. Part of the audio troubleshooting involved cloning the Retroarch source and adding more logging for local testing. The input issue turns out to have been a known issue.
I'm trying to troubleshoot issues that seem to be an interaction with Retroarch, OBS 30.2.2, streaming to Twitch, and maybe some USB issues. I'm not sure where to begin. I don't know if the issues are related or not. I've encountered both issues without OBS running, but much less regularly.
My question is: how should I set up logging to assess what's going wrong? It happens intermittently and I haven't been able to reliably reproduce it.
Sometimes Retroarch just totally stops taking inputs at all and I have to restart Retroarch. When that happens, it's usually after doing stuff with the keyboard, like F1 to go into the menu to remap buttons, or Command-Tabbing into my browser to do something in chat. Sometimes Retroarch doesn't output any audio. This usually happens if I open Retroarch after OBS in case I have to quit Retroarch to fix the first problem.
I can look at the OBS logs for today's stream, but it's not clear what I should be looking for. It's also not clear that Retroarch logged anything. The only things I can see online about logging with Retroarch are to run from the command line with -v and --logfile or by viewing the application output. Are the logs from the last time this happened lost?
I know this question's a little amorphous, but it's really not clear to me how to make it more precise.

Hi, welcome to Arqade! Your question seems to be asking how to perform basic troubleshooting, and has less to do with the game-specific software you mention. But it might be an edge case. I suggest to first try running the applications separately (maybe try streaming a game that doesn't require RetroArch, or only focus on playing a game without streaming), and see at what point which problem occurs. Reinstallation and updating drivers might also help at this point. Once a clear problem in a specific situation has been established, you can ask for help again. Good luck!

Thank you for your reply @Joachim. Yes, I am asking how best to troubleshoot my tech stack. I'm pretty new to this tech stack, though I'm not new to technology generally -- my professional background is in software development. As I stated, I encountered both issues without OBS running. I have hunches about factors that might contribute, but if I were to enumerate and try every combination of possible contributing factors, that would be dozens and dozens of combinations.

I will revise my question to be slightly more specific.

Or is this question off-topic for Arqade?

Sorry for the delay! Firstly, thanks for the thorough and well-written question, but I'm afraid it is indeed off-topic here. For general troubleshooting questions (the specifics still matter but they are circumstantial) you can try SuperUser or even StackOverflow. But first I would check with the RetroArch developers (e.g. here or through their Discord). Good luck! (BTW, you can flag your question for migration.)

@Joachim Oh cool! I learned something new: How to migrate questions!

FYI, I updated the question. Basically, I stumbled across both a known issue and a gap in the logging, so the answer to the question (were in on-topic) would have effectively been to download the source and figure it out.
